# Group rows having null value and a distinct value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to sum the last column (LeaveDays) and need the output in a single row by grouping all the columns but I am unable to group the rows here, and getting the same ungrouped result.
Thanks!

[image]

I need the output as:

```
YEAR   MONTHID   MONTH   C10 C11 C12 C13 C14 C15 C16 C17 C18 C19 C20 C21 C22 LEAVEDAYS

2020     6        JUNE    P   P   P   P   H   P   P   P   P   A   P   H   A    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there is other character than P found in C10 to C22, you are taking that other character into result.

I think you can use `max` with `keep` clause as follows:

```
SELECT
    YEAR, MONTHID, MONTH,
    MAX(C10) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY CASE WHEN C10='P' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS C10,
    ...,
    MAX(C22) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY CASE WHEN C22='P' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS C22,
    SUM(LEAVEDAYS) AS LEAVEDAYS
FROM your_table
GROUP BY
    YEAR, MONTHID, MONTH;
```

Or you can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT
    YEAR, MONTHID, MONTH,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN C10<>'P' THEN C10 END),'P') AS C10,
    ...,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN C22<>'P' THEN C22 END),'P') AS C22,
    SUM(LEAVEDAYS) AS LEAVEDAYS
FROM your_table
GROUP BY
    YEAR, MONTHID, MONTH;
```

Comment: Thanks! This really worked well in my case. I used the second option for my solution. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate by year and month, and use `COALESCE` to display `P` in case a given column has no non `NULL` value:

```
SELECT
    YEAR,
    MONTHID,
    MONTH,
    COALESCE(MAX(C10), 'P') AS C10,
    COALESCE(MAX(C11), 'P') AS C11,
    ...,
    COALESCE(MAX(C22), 'P') AS C22,
    SUM(LEAVEDAYS) AS LEAVEDAYS
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    YEAR,
    MONTHID,
    MONTH;
```

Comment: I have no issue in getting 'P' in place of null. I need the group all rows into a single row. Thanks.

Comment: My answer should be doing precisely that.  If not, then what is my answer doing?

Answer (score 0):

The logic that I understand is that you simply want the minimum value in each column:

```
SELECT YEAR, MONTHID, MONTH,
       MIN(C10) AS C10,
       ...,
       MIN(C22) AS C22,
       SUM(LEAVEDAYS) AS LEAVEDAYS
FROM t
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTHID, MONTH;
```